# Ajax Working Vind But did not Display result in dive

Tags: php, ajax, forms, html

I tried every thing which i using but ajax did not display the output in div BUT AJAX working fine.. is there any solution i could display result in div?

Tested in Firebug its display the reponse in XHR but display in DIV

Please solve me problem as soon as possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#signup_form").click(function() {

// we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
var name     = $('#name').attr('value');
var email     = $('#email').attr('value');
var passwords = $('#passwords').attr('value');
var passwords2 = $('#passwords2').attr('value');
var usernames = $('#usernames').attr('value');

var txt = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: "usernames=" + usernames + "& passwords="+ passwords + "& passwords2=" + passwords2 +"& email=" + email +"& name=" + name,
        success: function(data){
            //$('#messages').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
             $('#messages').val(data);

        }
    });
return false;
});
```

});

My Dive

```
  <div id="messages"> Message Display </div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#messages').html(data);
```

.val is for textboxes as such.